# Sort files (strings) over 4 arrays

Tags: php, sorting, hash

I am after a function which will let me sort a bunch of filenames over 4 arrays.
However, the a file must always end up in the same array - even if the number of files change.

Eg if I have files
myfile.html
anotherfile.html
morefiles.html
test.html

and my arrays
array1, array2, array3, array4

If I run this function then 
array1 might get myfile.html and anotherfile.html

If I run it again and add some more files (or less files, like not pass anotherfile.html) then I would still expect array1 to get myfile.html

So just need some way to hash the filename which I can then use to point to a certain array, so not a random or one that checks how many files are in each array needs to be consistent.

Comment: and what's the condition why `myfile.html` goes to `array1` and not `array2`?

Comment: That is my question.... like, perhaps you could do a crc32 on the file and if the result is odd goes to array1 but if the result is even goes to array2.. but that only handles two arrays (and using crc32 might not be best)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to solve a task like this, what is below is a *very* basic introduction to the topic. If it is useful, great otherwise I hope it at least gives an idea what where you might want to go (or not!).

This example simple takes a hash of the filename (in this case MD5 just because you're probably familiar with it). The `sscanf` just gets the first character of the hash and turns it into a number between 0 and 15 (since md5() returns a hexadecimal number). Since we only want to distribute between four arrays, the modulus operator (`%`) is used so that `$num` will always result in 0, 1, 2 or 3 which is then used as an array key (c.f. your $array1, $array2, etc.).

```
$files = array('a.html','b.html','c.html','d.html');
$arrays = 4;
$array = array_fill(0, $arrays, array());
// For each file name put it into the appropriate slot in $array
foreach ($files as $filename) {
    sscanf(md5($filename), '%1x', $hex);
    $key = $hex % $arrays;
    $array[$key][] = $filename;
}
// See what happened
var_dump($array);
```

For this particular example, the resulting array (which you can push into your separate variables if you like) has the following structure:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array()
    1 => array('c.html')
    2 => array('d.html')
    3 => array('a.html', 'b.html')
);
```

Comment: Thats fantastic! Right what I was after.